# How to Analyse and predict

Tags: statistical-significance, algorithms

I'm having a set of data's, say

```
Question,
Question's Main Category,Main Category followers,
Question's Related Categories,Each Related Categories followers,
Whether it got answer in 24hrs [Yes/No]
```

Now, I need to analyse a database with thousands of sets of data's like given above and predict whether the new given question(with all details like main category,followers...etc) will get answer in 24hrs or not ?

I have no idea which algorithm or statistical analysis will be more suitable to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your main goal is predicting if the new question will get an answer in 24h I suppose you should try with logistic regression. Anyways, more details about your data would be welcome since its hard to understand its structure.

Comment: yeah probit regression might work here